# NOT able to Save either VFP or APEX class

Tags: apex, visualforce, singleemailmessage

MY VFP:::

```
<apex:page controller="EmailControllerClass">
    <p>
        compose Email:::
    </p>
    <apex:form>
        
        <apex:outputLabel value="Send Email to:" for="To"/>
        <apex:inputText value="{!toMail}" id="To"/><br/>
        
        <apex:outputLabel value="CC Mail to:" for="CC"/>
        <apex:inputText value="{!ccMail}" id="CC"/><br/>
        
        <apex:outputLabel value="Reply Mail to:" for="rep"/>
        <apex:inputText value="{!repMail}" id="rep"/><br/>
        
        <apex:commandButton action="{!senEmail}" value="Send Email"/>
        
        
    </apex:form>
    
</apex:page>
```

---

MY APEX CLASS:::

```
public class EmailControllerClass 
{
    public string toMail{get; set;}
    public string ccMail{get; set;}
    public string repMail{get; set;}
    
    public void sendEmail()
    {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        
        email.setToAddresses(To);
        if(ccMail!=null && ccMail!='')
            email.setCcAddresses(CC);
        if(repMail!=null && repMail!='')
            email.setInReplyTo(repMail);
        
        email.setSubject('Test Subject');
        email.setPlainTextBody('Plain Text Body');
        
        try
        {
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{email});
        }
        catch(exception e)
        {
            system.debug(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you receiving an error? How are you saving these items? Please [edit] your post to provide complete details.

Comment: Did change in code and its woring now
`string[] To = new string[]{toMail};
        string[] CC = new string[]{ccMail};
        
        
        if(toMail!=null && toMail!='')
                email.setToAddresses(To);
        if(ccMail!=null && ccMail!='')
            email.setCcAddresses(CC);
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters you're using need to match valid variables.

This means that:

```
    email.setToAddresses(To);
```

Should be:

```
    email.setToAddresses(ToMail);
```

And:

```
        email.setCcAddresses(CC);
```

Should be something like:

```
        email.setCcAddresses(ccMail.split(','));
```

Comment: Thanks you ...I did change

`string[] To = new string[]{toMail};
  string[] CC = new string[]{ccMail};
        
      if(toMail!=null && toMail!='')
                email.setToAddresses(To);
      if(ccMail!=null && ccMail!='')
            email.setCcAddresses(CC); `